# add third party library to kotlin multiplatform mobile shared module

Tags: kotlin, aws-amplify, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Am writing a KMM mobile app that will be calling an AppSync API, my intention was to implement all the API calls in the shared module so that I don't have to write that code twice (i.e for iOS and Android separately)

Secondly, I want to use the Amplify libraries in the shared module to implement the API calls, am hoping this would allow me to take advantage of lots of features such as offline storage.

What I am noticing however is that even though I have successfully added the amplify libraries in the `commonMain` sourceSet, the libraries are not visible on the classpath so i can not import any class from the libraries

Here is my commonMain sourceSet dependencies in the `build.gradle`

```
val commonMain by getting {
  dependencies {
    implementation("com.amplifyframework:core:1.35.2")
    implementation("com.amplifyframework:aws-api:1.35.2")
   }
}
```

This builds successfully and installs the dependencies but i can't import anything

[image: screenshot]

My question here is,

- Does this mean that I can not add any third party that is not a kotlin multiplatform library at all?
- I feel like the only option this leaves me is to implement the API calls twice in a platform-specific way which kind of defeats the purpose of using KMM completely, is there an alternative solution that could allow me to use these libraries and write the API calls as shared code that is imported to both iOS and Android apps?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you cannot use non KMP libraries in common main. You can build networking using Ktor, which supports KMP. If you have to use amplify framework, you can create a wrapper using [expect/actual](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-connect-to-apis.html), and then use it in common module.

Comment: thank you I will try the  expect/actual approach

Comment: PylypDukhov where can I find an example for creating a wrapper?

Comment: Check out example under "Send and receive messages from a WebSocket" in the linked documentation: basically you need to mention all function you need to call from common code and implement them for each platform

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/v2/essentials/get-started-multiplatform.

This seems to work well with the KMM, I can build the API calls once and re-use for both platforms.

Comment: What's the best way for retrieving (authenticating), storing and passing tokens into KMM apollo though? Assuming you're using token based auth